# Lattice not contained in any connected subgroup is not contained in any positive dimensional subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, lattices

Let $ G $ be a simple Lie group and let $ \Gamma $ be a lattice in $ G $. If $ \Gamma $ is not contained in any connected subgroup of $ G $ does that imply that $ \Gamma $ is not contained in any positive dimensional subgroup of $ G $?

As pointed out in the comments, an equivalent way of saying this is: If $ \Gamma $ is not contained in any connected subgroup of $ G $ does that imply that the only Lie subalgebras $ \mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g} $ normalized by $ \Gamma $ are $ \mathfrak{h}=0 $ and $ \mathfrak{h}=\mathfrak{g} $?

Context:
I was thinking about the lattice $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ in $ SL(2,\mathbb{C}) $. $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ is not contained in any proper connected subgroup of $ SL(2,\mathbb{C}) $. And it is also true that $ SL(2,\mathbb{Z}) $ is not contained in any positive dimensional proper subgroup.

[Cross-posted on Math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828889/lattice-not-contained-in-any-connected-subgroup-is-not-contained-in-any-positive): it has been up on MSE for over a week with 1 upvote and no comments or answers so I thought MO might be better.

Comment: If $G$ is connected noncompact, Borel density says that $\Gamma$ is Zariski-dense. In particular, if $\Gamma\subset H$ with $H$ closed, then $\Gamma$ normalizes $\mathfrak{h}$ and hence $G$ normalizes $\mathfrak{h}$, so $\mathfrak{h}$ is either $\{0\}$ or $\mathfrak{g}$, which means that $H$ is either discrete or equal to $G$.

Comment: @YCor I see that takes care of the noncompact case. What if $ G $ is compact? Then the lattice $ \Gamma $ is just any finite subgroup. Does the ame conclusion still hold?

Comment: No, take some large enough dihedral group in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

Comment: @YCor ah good point. What if $ \Gamma $ is perfect like $ SL(2, \mathbb{Z}) $? Then does $ \Gamma $ not contained in any connected subgroup imply that $ \Gamma $ is not contained in any positive dimensional subgroup?

Comment: $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbf{Z})$ is not perfect.

Comment: @YCor oh good point it has the solvable quotients $ SL(2,2) $ and $ SL(2,3) $. I'm still curious if its possible to have a compact simple group $ G $ and a perfect finite subgroup $ \Gamma $ that normalizes some (nontrivial proper) connected subgroup but is not contained in any connected subgroup. $ SO(3), SU(3), SO(5), SU(4) $ don't have any counterexamples like that. Anyway, would you be willing to post your comments as an answer?